# Flutter: Text inside pdf file appears to be truncated

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, text

I'm creating a pdf file in flutter, and this file contains texts in both (English & Arabic).

The words in Arabic appears to be truncated, at first it show me the arabic text reversed, so I had to use re reverse the text, but at the end it appears truncated!!!

```
Text('$firstName $lastName'.split('').reversed.join(''),),
```

And this image show the pdf page:

[image]

So how can I make arabic words appears normal (connected letters) ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

I didn't imagine that my problem can be solve with using a parameter in the page widget in PDF package `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl` just like this simplicity.